# execute a function once in a specific time

Tags: vb.net

I have a code which checks for a specific time of the day to execute a function. To test it out I have the ff code:

```
 Private Sub tmrCheckTime_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrCheckTime.Tick
    If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= New TimeSpan(9, 00, 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

I was expecting the the `MessageBox.Show` would only happen once, but it keeps popping out, endlessly.

If I have a working function in there, it will probably run every second. How should I handle this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: add `tmrCheckTime.Enabled = False` after the messagebox ie shut off the timer once the time has past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking if you're past the time, so it remains true and keeps executing afterwards.
What you probably want is to the the tick of the timer to 1 day (instead of having it run all the time & checking if you should call the function again).

Also 1 day is a huge time, is this for a long running application? Sounds like the task scheduler is what you want and not a timer within your program.

Edit for clarification (the code version)

```
Private Sub tmrCheckTime_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrCheckTime.Tick   
    MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString)
```

End Sub

Then Inside your program where you register the timer:

```
this.Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tmrCheckTime_Tick,0,(1000*60*60*24));
// Timer is set in milliseconds so we set it to run every 1000 (millisecond => second) * 60 (second => minute) * 60 (minute => hour) * 24 (hour => day)
```

Comment: Timer has a max interval of ~65,000 ms

Comment: Thank you for that Info. Is there a task scheduler for .net 3.5?

Comment: Are you sure? Couldn't find that on MSDN doc. ALso sounds insanely low (that would be 65 seconds?) i really doubt this is the case.

Comment: No when i'm talking about a scheduler i mean non programming, just go into Windows, task scheduler, and Schedule your .exe to run once a day. But as i said if you must do it programatically just have the timer run once a day & remove your test in the code, it will be called once a day

Comment: Added sample code for the code version, no need to "check" the time, just set the timer to when you want it to execute, that's the whole point of the timer